# How to discover amount of pages of an external website

Tags: web

I have to make an offer for a new website. It should be based on the amount of pages there are in the existing site. There is no sitemap present.

Question: how can i get the total amount of pages inside an external website that not belong to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to reach a potential sitemap.xml file (http:www.yourwebsite.com/sitemap.xml)?

You can test pages discovery with an online sitemap generator : https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/

You can also try a Google research like this : site:www.yourwebsite.com. You'll see all indexed pages.

Comment: After several tryings finally get a sitemap report via https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/. Thanks for this suggestion.